# Machine Learning Correlated Records

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, spatial, mathematical-statistics

I am just getting started with machine learning and I have a question that I have had a hard time researching as I am not sure how to refer to it.

If I have a dataset:

```
TIMESTAMP    X      Y      Z     A   VAL
170103       10     20     21    2   6
170102       11     19     21    3   8
170101       9      19     18    2   10
161231       10     20     19    1   14
```

I want to predict VAL by training a regression model. 
I know that VAL is influenced by previous records, X, Y, Z and A.
X, Y and Z are also coordinates so they are spatially correlated.
How can I pre-process the data to account for the correlation between the rows or could someone please point me in the direction of some articles to read?

Comment: I noticed that you are using the regression tag.  Are you wanting to use regression specifically or does your question apply more broadly to all "machine learning" methods as your title implies?

Comment: I just want to point out that the first column `TIMESTAMP` suggests that the data not just spatially, but also temporarily corrrelated.